# Read a QR Code or Barcode in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, zxing

Please, does anyone know how to read a QR Code or Barcode in Xamarin Android? I only found examples in Xamarin Forms with the zxing library, but I NEED to do it only with Xamarin Android.

I tried to make the change from Xamarin Forms to only Xamarin Android but I had a lot of problems viewing the axml. My entire project is in Xamarin Android that's why I can't migrate to Xamarin Forms

Thank you so much

Comment: https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer but it does not solve the problem, the github does not show clear examples of how to build the interface in Xamarin Android, believe me, I tried it for many hours before asking my question here. thanks for your help too

Comment: There is an [entire sample](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/tree/master/Samples/Sample.Android) for Android

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [samples](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/tree/master/Samples) folder of  `ZXing.Net.Mobile`  contains both the sample of the form and the sample of `Android`. They're all together, so it doesn't seem so obvious.

For sample of Xamarin.Android, you can check link: [Sample.Android](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/tree/master/Samples/Sample.Android), just as Jason mentioned above. The sample include all the necessary codes we need.

You can copy all the necessary codes (including all the activities ,Layout files) to your code, and test it.

Note：

We also need to install nuget `Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V4` manually for our xamarin.android app if we use `AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentActivity` in code : [FragmentActivity.cs](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/master/Samples/Sample.Android/FragmentActivity.cs).

Comment: Hi @Samara Bravo, may I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If not, please share it in here. We can work together to figure it out.